# get the state in a url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, indexing

i've read [this article for ajax indexing](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/10/proposal-for-making-ajax-crawlable.html)

how can i do to read the state in a url like this with rails?

ex.

```
http://mysite.com/controller/action#!pid=1237604&id=1079297234
```

the state is:

```
pid=1237604&id=1079297234
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a couple of things here : 
1. The browser would not send you the parameters that come after the # , so you would need a client side javascript that converts these "pretty urls" into normal urls like :
http://mysite.com/controller/action?pid=1237604&id=1079297234

There is a good jquery [plugin](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/) available for this . Take a look at the samples that it implements for crawling . 
2. Apart from this , you would also need the mechanism to be able to handle the "ugly urls" that the googlebot sends . You can implement a small rack middle ware that transforms these ugly and pretty urls into normal urls that your rails app understands . Thus keeping this ajax indexing logic away from your app .

Answer (score -1):

in ruby/rails, you'd use the params hash

```
params["pid"]
```

Comment: Yes , however the real problem here is sending the params to the server .